# Structured Data Markup Helper: article about an event

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

With the [Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) (login required; see [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3069489?hl=en) instead), Google provides a way to markup a webpage with structured data, two of them being article and event.

What is the proper way to markup an article that describes some event? Should I nest event markup inside article markup? If yes, how would I do that?

Comment: Do you refer to [Google’ Rich Snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/21997?hl=en)? (it lists one for events, but not for articles … or do you mean products?) If so, which way are you using to implement them? Microdata (syntax) + Schema.org (vocabulary)?

Comment: Was referring to Structured Data Markup Helper: https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

It's either an article or an event. Not both.

If the purpose of the content is to promote the event, it's an event. If the article describes the event but isn't there to promote it (i.e. it's news coverage), it's an article.

Comment: You might want to update this answer, that's not at all true.